# Android: get time

Tags: android, timer

I have been thinking on timing my app, so I can know when an event happen. My first idea was to access to the system clock when I start the application and once again everytime I want to check the elapse time (then just substract). Don't know if this is the most accurate and optimal way. Any suggestion?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: you need a timer, look at class TimerTask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If millisecond resolution is enough, I'd use [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29). It's great for running quick performance checks.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I think it will be fine